# Is it safe to encrypt data by simply randomizing chunks based on a permutation?

Tags: encryption

Say I want to encrypt the following text: "Today is March the 22nd, 2015". And say want to encrypt 8-byte blocks of data using the following permutation [6,3,0,1,5,7,2,4] to swap characters at those indexes.

```
[T|o|d|a|y| |i|s| |M| a| r| c| h|  | t| h| e|  | 2| 2| n| d| ,|  | 2| 0| 1| 5]
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28
```

Using the encryption key [6,3,0,1,5,7,2,4], encrypting the first block goes like this:

First index is 6, so move the character at index 6 in the plain text to the first position of the ciphertext.

```
[i]
```

Second one is 3, so add the character at index 3 to the ciphertext:

```
[i|a]
```

When we finish the first block it looks like this (without the "|"):

```
[i|a|T|o| |s|d|y]
```

Then continue to do the same for the other blocks.

If the length if the text is not a multiple of the block size, just pad with some character and remove it after decryption.

I can't think of any type of attack except for brute force. This would basically mean generating all permutations of size n (where n is the block size). For block sizes larger than 1KB, it's basically computationally infeasible to break it.

Can anyone think of any other type of attack?

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about this one. Sorry.

Comment: @conectionist If you want, you could flag the question for a diamond mod to migrate it to [crypto.SE]

Answer (score 7):

This is called a [transposition cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transposition_cipher). It is the kind of thing that was commonplace before the invention of the computer, and some people were really good at breaking that in mere minutes (e.g. [Edgar Allan Poe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edgar_Allan_Poe)). In all generality, breakage is done by backtracking (wrong hypotheses on permutation elements leading to "impossible digraphs" that cannot occur in normal text).